# Can the immediate basin of attraction of super-attracting fixed point at 0 of a polynomial contain non-zero roots?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $f$ be a polynomial with a super attracting fixed point at $x=0$. Can the immediate basin of attraction of the fixed point contain other roots? If so, please provide a specific example with the immediate basin of attraction. If not, why?

Comment: How about $z^3-z^2$?

Comment: @Mark is zero an attracting fixed point? Is, say, $z=1/2$ attracted to zero?

Comment: @Mark is 1 in the immediate basin of attraction of 0? It is not obvious

Comment: what does super attracting mean ?

Comment: @Piyush A fixed point is super-attracting if the derivative is 0. It means the points in the basin of attraction approach specifically at an exponential rate. In this case, for $z$ in the basin of attraction,$ |f(z)-0|\approx b|z-0|^p$ for some constant p.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=az^2(z-1)$. Zero is superattracting. Now choose $a$ so small that
$|f(z)|<|z|/2$ for $|z|<2$. Then the root $z_0=1$ is in the immediate domain of
attraction.